# Ayuda con codigo para hacer consulta en base de datos sql

Tags: php, sql, base-de-datos, webservice

Necesito crear un formulario en un apartado de mi sitio web para que alumnos puedan checar sus calificaciones con su numero de control escolar (NCE) pero despues de muchos intentos y modificaciones no me funciona el código que encontré en un blog.

He intentado modificar los valores "NCE" del código, pasándolos de mayúsculas a minúsculas, corroborando los datos de acceso a la bdd y nada.

Al agregar el numero de control escolar de 9 dígitos (123456789) agregados en la bdd de sql y hacer la consulta desde el formulario no me muestra ni un resultado, solo me recarga la página.

Dentro de la base de datos se encuentran los campos:

> NCE: 123456789 Nombre: Jose Evaluacion: semestre Materia_1: 100
>   Materia_2: 100 Materia_3: 100 Materia_4: 100 Materia_5: 100 Materia_6:
>   100 Materia_7: 100 Materia_8: 100 Materia_9: 100 Materia_10: 100
>   PROMEDIO: 100

Los archivos y código que uso es el siguiente:

Todos los archivos se encuentran en la misma ruta.

```
index.php :
<form action="resultados.php" method="post">
No de control escolar: <input type="text" name="nce">
<br>
<input type="submit" name="enviar" value="enviar">
</form>



resultados.php:
<?php 
if(isset($_POST['enviar'])) 
{ 
if(!empty($_POST['NCE'])) 
{     
include "auth.php"; 

$nce=$_POST['NCE'];  

conectar();     

$q = "SELECT * FROM nombretabladebasededatos WHERE ID='$NCE'";  

$resEmp = mysql_query($q) or die(mysql_error());  

desconectar(); 

$totEmp = mysql_num_rows($resEmp); 

if($totEmp>0) 

{ 
while ($rowEmp = mysql_fetch_assoc($resEmp))  
{  
echo "Nombre: <strong>".$rowEmp['Nombre']."</strong><br></br>";  
echo "Evaluacion:<strong>".$rowEmp['Evaluacion']."</strong><br></br>";  
echo "Nota Primer Lapso: ".$rowEmp['Materia_1']."<br></br>";  
echo "Nota Segundo Lapso: ".$rowEmp['Materia_2']."<br></br>";  
echo "Nota Tercer Lapso: ".$rowEmp['Materia_3']."<br> 
</br>";  
echo "Nota Definitiva: ".$rowEmp['Materia_5']."<br></br>"; 

echo "Nota Definitiva: ".$rowEmp['Materia_6']."<br></br>"; 

echo "Nota Definitiva: ".$rowEmp['Materia_7']."<br></br>"; 

echo "Nota Definitiva: ".$rowEmp['Materia_8']."<br></br>"; 

echo "Nota Definitiva: ".$rowEmp['Materia_9']."<br></br>"; 

echo "Nota Definitiva: ".$rowEmp['Materia_10']."<br></br>"; 

echo "Nota Definitiva: ".$rowEmp['PROMEDIO']."<br></br>";   
} 
} 
else 
{ 
header("location:index.php");  
} 
} 
else 
{ 
header("location:index.php");  
}     
} 
else 
{ 
header("location:index.php");      
} 
?>


auth.php :
<?php 
function conectar()
{
mysql_connect("localhost","usuario","contraseña");

mysql_select_db("nombrebasededatos");
}
function desconectar()
{
mysql_close();
}
?>
```

En teoría debería lanzarme en la pagina los valores de la tabla/consulta en la base de datos pero se vuelve a mostrar el formulario.

¿alguna idea?

Comment: parece que el problema pueda estar en la linea `if(!empty($_POST['NCE'])) `; estas comprobando el post de NCE en mayuscula, pero en el formulario lo defines como `<input type="text" name="nce">`. (en minuscula). Echa un vistazo, puede que este saltando al else de esa condicion y por eso te muestre el formulario de nuevo.

Comment: Lo intenté pero pasa lo mismo, mira

www.miprepanogales.mx/formatos/

Comment: Agregando mayúsculas en todas partes me lleva a 
www.miprepanogales.mx/formatos/resultados.php pero sin resultados

Comment: he probado a enviarte con postman NCE y enviar, y me da un 500 internal server error. podrias mirar el archivo error.log a ver si nos da mas info al respecto? puede que haya algo mal escrito y no lo estemos viendo...

Comment: Stack trace:
#0 /home/knn3rr890qni/public_html/formatos/resultados.php(11): conectar()
#1 {main}
  thrown in /home/knn3rr890qni/public_html/formatos/auth.php on line 5

Comment: Ya corroboré los datos de conexión y me sigue marcando el mismo error

Comment: el error dice que hay un problema en la funcion conectar() del archivo auth.php. Dado que ya has revisado la conexion, prueba a poner algo como : `mysql_connect('localhost', 'usuario_mysql', 'contraseña_mysql') or die( mysql_error());
` para ver que error te da en la conexion. Al menos sabes que es en ese archivo

Comment: Me sigue marcando error de conexión

[17-Jan-2019 16:34:38 UTC] PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function mysql_connect() in /home/knn3rr890qni/public_html/formatos/auth.php:4
Stack trace:
#0 /home/knn3rr890qni/public_html/formatos/resultados.php(11): conectar()
#1 {main}
  thrown in /home/knn3rr890qni/public_html/formatos/auth.php on line 4


Ya creé un nuevo usuario y me marca el mismo error, inclusive agregar "localhost:3306" por aquello de la ubicación pero todo sigue igual.

Comment: parece cosa de que estes utilizando php7. la funcion mysql_connect() desaparece en esa version. Prueba a utilizar `mysqli_connect()` o pdo. revisa http://php.net/manual/es/function.mysql-connect.php, ahi te dice que en la version php7 se quita esa funcion

Comment: Buscaré entonces, muchas gracias :)